# Neo4j finding path by the same relationship property

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, nosql

I working on neo4j and I have an question about them.I have 2 nodes and I want to find same relations between these two nodes.And all relations must have same property.I executed cypher query that is in the following segment of code:

```
START a=node(1), d=node(4) 
MATCH p=a-[r:ROUTE*..]-d 
WITH head(relationships(p))as r1,last(relationships(p))as r2,p
WHERE r2.RouteID = r1.RouteID
return p;
```

When I try to execute that query, neo4j is crashing.How can I find that path? Is my query looking correct?

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that 1 and 4 are actually valid node IDs.

Otherwise, your Cypher looks legal to me (although, you could simplify `[r:ROUTE*..]` to `[r:ROUTE*]`).

Comment: I get "Unknow Error", when I execute that query with changed [r:Route*] parameter.Why it gaves me that?

Comment: Again, make sure that 1 and 4 are valid node IDs. What do you get for `START a=node(1), d=node(4) RETURN a, d`?